# Test if <span> is visible with ng-show attribute

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, selenium, protractor

In my view I need to test if `ng-show="showMsgRoundDownToHours"` makes a span visible. This is the view:

```
<div class="highlight">
    ...     
    <span class="MsgRoundDownToHours" ng-show="showMsgRoundDownToHours">
       {{msgRoundDownToHours}}
    </span><br>
    ...
</div>
```

This is my Protractor Test for that scenario:

```
describe('c2g test', function() {
  ...
  var showMsgRoundDownToHours = element(by.css('.MsgRoundDownToHours'));
  ...
  // 10km and 229 minutes)
  it('10km, 229 minutes', function() {
    ...
    expect(showMsgRoundDownToHours).toBe(false);
    ...
  });
});
```

I don't know how to select that particular span. I've tried making the `span` a `div`, but this breaks the layout. I've tried assigning it a css class `MsgRoundDownToHours`, but this makes my console explode with errors. Is there any other way to select that span? I'm happy to do css modifications as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find the element and check the visibility using [`isDisplayed()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.isDisplayed):

```
expect(element(by.css('span.MsgRoundDownToHours')).isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
```